# people picker in sharepoint

Tags: powershell

I have recently configured a two way domain trust between two domains.And I want people picker to be able to see across only one domain. I have done  this by setting stsadm property through command.I had applied this command to every web app one by one.But I could not find a way to set this across multiple web apps.Can anybody  pls tell me how to set people picker property of all the web apps or web apps under specific domain  that are in the sharepoint instead of setting it to every single app one by one.

Thanx

Comment: Are you using SP2010 or MOSS2007?

Comment: I am using SP2010

Answer (score 1):

this can only be done per webapplication.
Use PowerShell to automate the process of setting it for a subset or all of the webapplication

http://blogbaris.blogspot.co.at/2011/10/limiting-sharepoint-people-picker-with.html